# Getting warning: Name 'guess' can be undefined

Tags: python-3.x, loops, random

I am getting warning for the last `guess` in the last `if` statement. Can I just ignore that and be sure, there is no case for my program to work incorrectly?

```
import random
print('Try to guess hidden number from 1 to 50, U have 6 tries by the way')
hidden_num = random.randint(1, 50)
tries = 6
while tries>0:
    guess = int(input(f'Guess the hidden number, tries left: {tries}\n'))
    tries-=1
    if guess == hidden_num:
        print('Great Job, You got it!')
        break
    elif guess < hidden_num:
        print('U were so close, take a bit higher')
    else:
        print('WowWo! Pick lower,Dude!')
if guess != hidden_num and tries == 0:
    print('Don\'t be upset buddy, you have whole life ahead!')
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a false positive in the linter.

Comment: What's the problem?? I executed your code, it worked perfectly

Comment: I am using Pycharm, it works fine, but  it gives me a warning about the last `guess` @AbhijitShirwal

Comment: @Codi if your program is working well, leave it. If you run your program in python's official ide, then there won't be any problem

Comment: what is the pycharm warning? can you share with us?

Comment: @nima It was in the title:
Name 'guess' can be undefined

Comment: The warning is correct, if you leave the last statement outside the 'while' loop, at that line 'guess' could be undefined. 
'guess' is defined inside the loop, there's a chance the loop will not execute, so 'guess' would be undefined. Its just a reminder to check if this is the wanted desire.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the warning issue, just by tabing last if condition, but still don't understand what is the code execution difference between this 2 cases:

```
    if guess != hidden_num and tries == 0:
        print('Don\'t be upset buddy, you have whole life ahead!')
```

and:

```
if guess != hidden_num and tries == 0:
    print('Don\'t be upset buddy, you have whole life ahead!')
```